# Django Admin - insert custom HTML code for specific model admin?

Tags: django

How can I insert custom HTML code for specific model admin? Or maybe it is possible to render template and insert result into specific model admin page? I don't want to override behaviour of standart components, just want to add some visual elements and javascript code to that page.

Comment: define a templatetags and find a way to insert it in the admin page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [override some admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) by app and/or by model by placing them in a directory structures like these:

- `templates/admin/my_app/`      (all apps models)
- `templates/admin/my_app/my_model/`    (specific model)

You should be able to add any HTML you want that way.

These are the specific templates you can override by app or model:

- app_index.html
- change_form.html
- change_list.html
- delete_confirmation.html
- object_history.html

Comment: The link is a 404 nowadays. Here is the current (3.2) page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Red, updated link in my response :)